# Remove Add to cart only single product page

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to remove the add to cart button from the single product page. someone help, please?

**here my code, but not working for me**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_to_product_page', 1 );
function remove_add_to_cart_to_product_page () {
if ( get_option ( 'wcs_remove_cart_to_product' ) == 'yes') {
    if ( is_product () ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart'); } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove add to cart button from single product page you can use below snippet:

```
add_action('wp', 'your_function_name' );
function your_function_name(){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30);
}
```

You can also set priority to the action:

```
add_action('wp', 'your_function_name',99);
function your_function_name(){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30);
}
```

You can use WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook :https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html